# Remove the first day of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
                         X
Datetime                      
2017-01-01 01:00:00   3129.3460
2017-01-01 02:00:00   5433.4315
2017-01-01 03:00:00   2351.8391
2017-01-01 04:00:00   6788.3210
2017-01-01 05:00:00   1232.8655
                         ...
2022-08-14 20:00:00  8905.5340
2022-08-14 21:00:00  8623.0765
2022-08-14 22:00:00  9054.8312
2022-08-14 23:00:00  10341.4785
2022-08-15 00:00:00  9341.1234
```

How can i remove the whole day of data, if the first hour of that day is different from zero? In this case, i need to remove the whole `2017-01-01` day.

So i thought of using an `if` condition with `df.drop()`

```
first_data = df.index.min()

if first_data.day != 0:
    df = df.drop(first_data)
```

But i am not sure what i should pass as argument to `df.drop`. In the above code, it will only drop the first hour of that first day, since `first_data` gives me the whole timestamp from years until seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `groupby` and `filter`

```py
out = (df.groupby(df.index.date)
       .filter(lambda g: str(g.index.min().time()) == '00:00:00'))
```

```
print(out)

                             X
2022-08-15 00:00:00  9341.1234
2022-08-15 01:00:00  9341.1234
```

Comment: Well, that actually works, but i didn't understand at all what you did there.

Comment: @Murilo Which part you don't understand, the code is self explaining.

Comment: Ok, i think i get it now. But correct me if i am wrong please. You are  `grouping by`  my `df` by date. Then, you filter it by applying a lambda function that will remove any of those dates that don't have a min index of `time == 00:00:00`?

Comment: @Murilo Exactly, but to be more accurate, grouping the df by the index date. Then keep the group where min index time is 00:00:00.